# Trouble understanding stated consequence of the division theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

**Question:** I'm having some trouble understanding the following Corollary (and construction of its proof) given in the book *"An Introduction to Mathematical Reasoning"*.

The main reason being the condition $0 \le q \lt r$, which seems to me non-sense because it would imply that $0 \lt r$, so that $r$ couldn't be zero (contradicting the corollary itself!).

Also, regarding the second sentence of the construction of the proof, wouldn't $gcd(b, r)$ and $gcd(b, 0)$ be two other possible solutions?

> **Corollary**: Let $a$ and $b$ be integers with $b \gt 0$ and suppose that $a = bq +r$ for integers $q$ and $r$ with $0 \le q \lt r$. Then $b$ divides $a$ if and only if $r = 0$.
>
> **Construction of the proof**: The point here is that if $b$ divides $a$ then, for some integer $q_1$, $a=bq_1=bq_1+r_1$ with $r_1 = 0$. So if $a=bq+r$ with $0 \lt r \lt q$ then $gcd(q, r)$ and $gcd(q_1, 0)$ would be two distinct solutions to the division problem, contradicting the uniqueness part of the division theorem.

For completeness, I leave the statement of the division theorem as given in the book.

> **Division theorem**: Let $a$ and $b$ be integers with $b \gt 0$. Then there are unique integers $q$ and $r$ such that
> $$a = bq + r \quad and \quad 0 \le r \lt b$$

Thank you.

Comment: For your first question, yes, that's surely a typo and should be $0\le r<q$.

Comment: @GregMartin It should be $0 \leqslant r < b$, not $< q$.

Comment: Definitely a typo.  It's supposed to be 0 <= r < q. Second question:  the proof never claimed they were the only solutions. Gcd(b,r) and gcd (b0) may be also be solutions but we do not know if they are distinct.

Comment: @DanielFischer That got me a little more confused; isn't it a valid assumption that $0 \le r \lt q$ ?

Comment: @bender No, $q$ is the quotient - $\bigl\lfloor \frac{a}{b}\bigr\rfloor$ - If $a < 0$, then we also have $q < 0$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For your first question, yes, that's surely a typo and should be $0\le r<q$.

As for the second question: I'm pretty sure those gcds shouldn't be there—it seems that they want to say that the *ordered pairs* $(q,r)$ and $(q_1,0)$ are two distinct solutions to the division problem.

Comment: My bad - I misunderstood those ordered pairs by gcds.